How to write Laravel Blade syntax inside jQuery or JavaScript?
I have an old Laravel project (version 8). In it, I have Blade templates with code like the following.
<div id='product-container'>
  @if(home_base_price($product) != home_discounted_base_price($product))
    <del class="fw-600 opacity-50 mr-1">
      {{ home_base_price($product) }}
    </del>
  @endif
  {{ show_percentage($product_price) }} 
  {{ $product->product_image }}
  {{ $product->getTranslation('name') }}
  // These syntaxes are written along with other HTML/CSS code.
</div>
<button id="load_more_button" class="btn btn-primary">Show more</button>

I'm fetching product data from an AJAX request in JSON format with a jQuery script and trying to append the HTML content as new products when clicking the show more button (on click pagination).
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var start = 12; 
    $('#load_more_button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://example.com/load-more-products",
            method: "GET",
            data: {
                start: start
            },
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#load_more_button').html('Loading...');
                $('#load_more_button').attr('disabled', true);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.data.length > 0) {
                    var html = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                        var product = data.data[i];
                        html += '<div id="product-container">' +
                        <!-- I want to write the Blade syntaxes that have been used in the Blade template, here -->            
                        '</div>';
                    }
                    // rest code

</script>

How do I write the Blade syntaxes inside the jQuery script?

You can't. Blade syntax is processed with PHP, which is all done before the page is sent to the browser. Anything javascript is processed after the page is sent, so it doesn't know anything about blade syntax. What you can try doing is have the ajax request generate and render the view, which would send it back as HTML

thanks could you please give a little more hint on how do i acheieve this?

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views should help point you in the right direction

If this is a newish project you can consider using livewire which takes away some of the complexity of keeping the UI in sync with your models. Another alternative is to use JS libraries/frameworks like React or Vue.

@apokryfos this is not a new project. Thanks for the insights.

Blade syntax only works in a PHP file with a .blade.php extension. So, you have two options.

Make the script a .blade.php file and use @include to call it into your blade file.

Have a <script></script> tag in your blade file. Define the variables there and call them in the JS/jQuery script. An example of this is given below


<script>
  var var1 = '{{ $variable1 }}';
  var var2 = '{{ $variable1 }}';
</script>

If the variables are not detected in the script, remove the var keyword and try again.

you could use
<script> var myvariable = "{{$phpVar}} </script>

Add this in your file_name.blade.php at the top
<script>
  // Safely retrieve Blade variables and assign default values to avoid errors
  var contactPhone = @json($phoneNumber ?? 'No phone number available');
  var contactEmail = @json($emailAddress ?? 'No email address available');
</script>

-- Optionally you can also use @yeild('headerScript') rather than to define in the middle of your webpage --
Get in your app.js
  // Log the variables to the console for debugging (optional)
  console.log("Contact Phone:", contactPhone);
  console.log("Contact Email:", contactEmail);

